# Eclipse (STS) HTTP Proxy Configuration

Tags: eclipse, proxy, spring-tool-suite

I upgraded from Spring Tool Suite (STS) 3.2 to STS 3.3 and it has brought a few issues with it.

When trying to download plugins, I get "Proxy Authentication Required.." errors.

I have my http proxy configured correctly (the same way as 3.2).  I have even compared all the .ini files between the versions and cannot find a difference.

As many posts have suggestion, I have also cleared the SOCKS proxy, and even tried to specify in the .ini files that it is not to be used- but again without any luck.

I have tried configuring the HTTPS proxy and playing with the properties in the .ini files for both, restarts, running under different permissions, ect...

Could use some new ideas on this one.

Thanks a lot for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same thing just happened to me on installing STS 3.4.  I could only get the proxy to work by switching my proxy provider to manual, editing the http schema and adding my proxy username and password.  Less than ideal.

If I remove STS, the native proxy provider starts working again.

Comment: I never came back to answer this question, but you are right. The thing is with my installation, even updating these proxy settings did not fix the issue- it still wouldn't connect. I rolled back to a previous version, changed the proxy settings, and it's been working fine ever since.  I suppose I'll just wait for the next update.

Comment: The same for me. Other versions of eclipse worked, but STS failed the Proxy Authentication. Did any of you find a way to fix this without having to set it to manual?

Comment: In STS 3.6 on Win7 proxy won't follow IExplorer's settings. Needed to set this up manually by going to Windows -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections -> Active Provider: Manual.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. It turned out that this was caused by two plugins. To allow your STS to connect to the internet via proxy just delete this two plugins:

- org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore_4.2.4.v201305222326.jar
- org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient_4.2.5.v201305222326.jar

There should be older versions of this plugins so everything should be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add the following 2 lines to STS.ini file. The first line at the top of the file and the second line at the bottom of the STS.ini file:

```
-clean
...
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

Then on the following file, which exists in the STS (Eclipse) installation folder...

```
configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.core.net.prefs
```

...I had to enable proxies making sure that the following properties were set to true:

```
proxiesEnabled=true
systemProxiesEnabled=true
```

Only after doing this and rebooting STS, the proxy settings I had entered through the UI previously, took effect.

Edit (2020-01-30):
If the file **org.eclipse.core.net.prefs** doesn't exist, just create with the following basic content. Edit as needed.

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
nonProxiedHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|another-host-in-your-LAN
org.eclipse.core.net.hasMigrated=true
proxiesEnabled=true
systemProxiesEnabled=true
proxyData/HTTP/hasAuth=true
proxyData/HTTP/host=your-proxy
proxyData/HTTP/port=80
proxyData/HTTPS/hasAuth=true
proxyData/HTTPS/host=your-proxy
proxyData/HTTPS/port=80
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-3647

It is recommended to download the latest nightly build.